# Doctrine extension :: search entity by other field than ID

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, translation

Using doctrine extension, when locale changes, searching an entity with, say ID=1, returns proper values for the current locale (stored in translations table), which is a great thing, but what if I need to search for entities by another field, like name or something..

Is there any way to get proper results using other entity field/property that ID?

Comment: What you are using for searching by ID?

Comment: https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md

Comment: try use `$em->findBy(array('name' => 'example')`

Comment: Belive me, I tried.. Did you succeeded using the above?

Comment: yes, did you tried to get an repository:
`$em->getRepository('MyProject\Entity')->findBy(array('name' => 'example'));`

Comment: Just to be clear: $categRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository ("RamaCmsBundle:ProductCategory"); $categ = $categRepo->findOneBy (array('webName' =>'somePage'));

Comment: Ricardo, are you using translatable doctrine extension?

Comment: I use the same get repository function:
`$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Entity:Product')`
But I not using an translatable doctrine extension =/

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT pc FROM MyDomain\Model\ProductCategory pc WHERE pc.webName LIKE :name")
$query->setParameter("name", $name);
$query->getResult();
```